# Does use of OpenID Connect for login imply Google can impersonate my users?

Tags: google, openid-connect

I am looking at integrating Google OpenID Connect (OAuth 2.0 for Login) as a login option for a web application.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect

My question: Does use of OpenID Connect (and similar schemes) imply that Google could impersonate my users, log on to my website, and access all their data there?

My guess is that the answer might be different for the "server flow" versus "implicit flow" (see Google link), with the latter involving javascript in the browser.  But depending on underlying implementation on Google's side, I'm not sure about either.

I don't believe Google has any interest in committing criminal acts of unauthorized network access, but on the other hand, a vulnerability is a vulnerability and I want to understand the real relationship of the systems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verification is not directly performed by you, so in principle yes, Google could fake the identity of any of its users upon authentication.

What happens during the authentication is that your service contact Google OpenID provider and asks: *"who is this user?"*. Google answer will be along the lines of *"this user is foo.bar@gmail.com and **I have verified it**"*. It's a matter of trust. You have to trust the *authentication provider* to perform that verification.